# blazor: state is not updated when value is changed

Tags: blazor

I am trying to simply show and hide two divs, depending on the state of the bool "showPanel2".

This is what I did:

```
<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Gagger</a>
        <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="mainpage" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div hidden="@showPanel2" class="nav-item px-3">
           <NavLink class="nav-link" href="login">
               <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Login
           </NavLink>
       </div>
        <div hidden="@(!showPanel2)" style="" class="nav-item px-3">
           <NavLink class="nav-link" href="login">
               <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Logout
           </NavLink>
       </div>
    </nav>
</div>



@code {

    static bool showPanel2 = false;

    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }

    public static void Reload()
    {
        showPanel2 = true; 

    }
}
```

So basically the reload function is called from another component and it does change the value in the bool. This should now trigger a change in the UI but it doesnt.

What is wrong here?

Comment: When you call Reload from another component, it does not refresh the state of the component. Overall, this approach won't take you to the desired result. Read up on the Parameter and EventCallBack from the official documentation.

Comment: The logic works perfectly fine: https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/GnEsdbvd237tGYPY42

Comment: this is exactly what i wrote and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is:

```cs
    public static void Reload()
    {
        showPanel2 = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

You need to call `StateHasChanged` because `Reload` is not a UI event and therefore doesn't trigger an automated render of the component.

However, this is not a good pattern for solving inter component communications.

Recognise that you are dealing with state and encapsulate that state in an object.

```cs
public class NavMenuState
{
    public bool LoggedIn { get; private set; }

    public event EventHandler? LoggedInStateChanged;

    public void SetLoggedIn(bool value)
    {
        if (this.LoggedIn != value)
        {
            this.LoggedIn = value;
            this.LoggedInStateChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

You now have a controlled way of mutating state and notifying interested parties of a change.

Next you need to make the state object available to your components.

There are two ways to do this:

1. Register `NavMenuState` as a Scoped service and the inject it where you need it.
2. Cascade it in `MainLayout`, which I will show here.

```cs
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>SO77015680</PageTitle>
<CascadingValue Value="_navMenuState" IsFixed>

//... content here

</CascadingValue>

@code {
    private NavMenuState _navMenuState = new();
}
```

`NavMenu` gets the cascaded parameter and registers a handler on the event to render the page if a change occurs.

```cs
@implements IDisposable

//... Menu  stuff

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass nav-scrollable" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div hidden="@(!navMenuState.LoggedIn)" class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="login">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Login
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div hidden="@(navMenuState.LoggedIn)" style="" class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="login">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Logout
            </NavLink>
        </div>
      //... Menu  stuff
    </nav>
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private NavMenuState navMenuState { get; set; } = default!;

    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(navMenuState);
        this.navMenuState.LoggedInStateChanged += OnNavMenuStateChanged;
    }

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }

    private void OnNavMenuStateChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        => StateHasChanged();

    public void Dispose()
        => this.navMenuState.LoggedInStateChanged -= OnNavMenuStateChanged;
}
```

Here's `Index` making changes to the state.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SwitchState">Change</button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private NavMenuState? navMenuState { get; set; }

    private void SwitchState()
    {
        this.navMenuState?.SetLoggedIn(!this.navMenuState.LoggedIn);
    }
}
```