# Blazor: Change List of another component, after render

Tags: blazor

I have this div inside my component A:

```
                <div class="imageContainer">
                    <img class="image" src="@Helpers.Converters.ReturnBase64ImageSourceFromBase64String(SingleMeme.Base64Image)" />
                    @{
                        bool hideMe = false;
                        if (!SingleMeme.IsSpoiler) hideMe = true;
                        else hideMe = false; 
                        <div hidden="@hideMe" class="thehider">
                            HIDE ME PLEASE!! :(
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
```

But I also have a swith in another component B:

```
<input  @onchange="HandleCheckboxChange" type="checkbox">
```

Now I want component B to be able to hide everyhing, where it says "hide me please". But a list with elements are already on the screen.

How can I show / hide elements from component a with a button click on component b?

Comment: See the extended answer to your previous question which demonstrates accepted patterns for handling inter component communications with either a cascaded or Scoped Service state context. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77016453/13065781

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind both components to a bool property into your view and create an EventCallback on component B.

MyViews.razor:

```
<ComponentA IsVisible="MyBool" />
<ComponentB @bind-Value="MyBool" />

@code {
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }
}
```

ComponentA.razor

```
<div class="imageContainer">
    @if (!IsVisible)
    {
        <div class="thehider">
            HIDE ME PLEASE!! :(
        </div>
    }    
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
}
```

ComponentB.razor

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind="Value" />

@code {
    private bool _Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool Value
    {
        get => _Value;
        set
        {
            if (_Value == value) return;
            _Value = value;
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> ValueChanged { get; set; }
}
```

**Explanation:**

Both components are binding to MyBool property on view, the Component A has a one way binding, so it's just reading this property.

The Component B use encapsulation to implement a two way binding, so every time you click on checkbox it's enter on Value property setter, it sets the value from property _Value and invoke the EventCallback, this callback will notify the parent view, that did a bind to this component.

The parent view, after the EventCalback notification, it will change the MyBool  property, and since ComponentA do bind to the same property it will Show or Hide the element based on MyBool value.